# How do I get rid of file name at the end of website URL?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, filenames

For example, I have a website called `example.com` and when I go to my "about me" page, the URL is then `example.com/about.html` and it's the same for every page I go to, the URL is just the name of my file.

I can't figure out how to change this, I've tried googling it but I don't exactly know what this is called and I couldn't find much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)